# Nodejs - Multiple Requests to End Point with Asynchronous Process

Tags: node.js, api, http, express

I am reasonably new to Nodejs development.

I am curious about multiple requests in close succession to an end point URL where an asynchronous process is involved.

```
ie

app.post("/endpoint", function(req, res) {

  var input = req.body.data

 .... 

asynchronous code here

})
```

So user A hits request. Input takes data. User A is waiting on an async process so Node takes next request at this end point. Var now over written.?

So I assume Node would not do this and fulfil user A request first... No more than one request at a time on an end point.

Is this determined by a server response? All requests must have a response?

Any info would be great?

Answer (score 0):

If the input variable was outside the scope of the post function then it would be overwritten. Example:

```
var input
app.post("/endpoint", function(req, res) {

  input = req.body.data

   //.... 

   //asynchronous code here

})
```

But since its inside the scope it makes it unique to that one request. The downside to it being unique to the one request is that it cant be accessed outside the request unless you save it somewhere else and it is also deleted once all the code(including async code) from the request has finished processing.

Comment: So if user A is in the endpoint request,  this endpoint will not process another request until user A has received response?

Comment: @SteveW. No, multiple requests can be handled at once so long as they are asynchronous. If your code is **synchronous** then only one can be handled at once. Node is single threaded but when you do something asynchronously it allows other tasks (such as other requests) to do something while it is waiting for the asynchronous task to complete. Each request triggers a separate invocation of your handler so it has its own scope for the arguments and the variables declared inside that function.

Comment: So from my understanding, User A and User B hit the same endpoint/URL almost simultaneously and Node passes User A and their local variables to a thread and then User B and their local variables to a thread to be processed.  Even tho the event loop is single threaded simultaneous requests are processed multi-threaded?